# Find the area of the polygon in the figure

Tags: geometry

In the triangle in the figure the area of the triangle $MBP$ is equal to $9$, the area of the triangle $NPC$ is equal to $8$ and the area of the triangle $BCP$ is equal to $24$. I need to figure out the area of the polygon $AMPN$.

[image]

Notice that $M$ and $N$ are NOT the midpoints of $AB$ and $AC$.

It seems to me we don't have enough elements to figure this out. Moreover, I've been trying to find similarities between the shown triangles but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have enough data. Draw the segment $MN$, then considering the triangles $MBC,MNC$, which share the same split base $MPC$, we have
$$\frac9{24}=\frac{A(\triangle MPN)}8$$
So $A(\triangle MPN)=3$. Now let $A(\triangle AMN)=x$, then by the same logic as before
$$\frac x{9+3}=\frac{x+3+8}{9+24}$$
$$\frac x{12}=\frac{x+11}{33}$$
$$33x=12(x+11)=12x+132$$
$$21x=132\qquad x=\frac{44}7$$
Then $A(AMPN)=3+\frac{44}7=\frac{65}7$.

Comment: Thank you! But why we can have the first proportion? Are there  any similarities?

Comment: @Schiele Because $MPN,PCN$ have the same height, and $MBP,PBC$ have the same height.